# Telerik Loading Panel background images not showing in IE8

Tags: asp.net, image, internet-explorer-8, background, telerik

I have a website using Telerik controls for ASP.NET.  When an AJAX request starts, the Loading Panel (defined in the master page) will display, with a loading image, text, and faded white background color. It works totally fine in Firefox and Chrome, but the background image and text don't display in IE8.  All that displays is the white background.

LoadingPanel code:

```
<tel:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="HBApplicationWideLoadingPanel" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" 
        AnimationDuration="400" InitialDelayTime="0" CssClass="LoadingPanel" IsSticky="true" >
    <div id="HBApplicationWideLoadingPanelLabel" class="LoadingPanelLabel">Loading</div>
</tel:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

Any ideas why IE8 isn't displaying the images? I've inspected the page source, and they're there in the CSS.

Comment: You seen to have ommited your LoadingPanel code.

Comment: Can you provide a demo page (link) that shows the issue?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "faded white background"? Are you using the built in "Transparency" property? Are you setting a white background on the RadAjaxLoadingPanel and then setting the transparency in your own style sheet? It sounds like you might be seeing the white background b/c your transparency setting isn't being applied properly, so the images you see in other browsers aren't visible in IE because the white background covers them. Opacity works differently in different browsers (and versions). Ready [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) on the different styles you can use to implement transparency in different browsers. Or just use the built-in Transparency property of the RadAjaxManager. If I'm way off the mark, please elaborate on your problem so I can assist you further.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Might be some kind of overlay or z-index quirk from which only IE suffers. My advice is to use IE dev toolbar to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you don't set the Transparency attribute on the RadAjaxLoadingPanel.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel" runat="server" 
    </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

works

but

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel" runat="server" Transparency="10"
    </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

doesn't work properly in IE8